# ManagedForm With Text On ToolBar

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface

I have a very simple `ManagedForm` with a toolbar on the top right:

```
    this.managedForm = new ManagedForm(this);
    this.managedForm.getToolkit().decorateFormHeading(this.managedForm.getForm().getForm());

    IToolBarManager toolbarManager = this.managedForm.getForm().getToolBarManager();
    IMenuService menuService = (IMenuService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IMenuService.class);
    menuService.populateContributionManager((ContributionManager) toolbarManager, toolBarUri);
    toolbarManager.update(true);
```

I want to show the labels of the commands in the toolbar (because E4 doesn't scale for UHD displays correctly and you can't make out the toolbar otherwise). How do I do that?

Comment: Possibly `mode="FORCE_TEXT"` on the `command` for each toolbar item.

Comment: @greg-449 Cumbersome, but works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) said: by using `mode="FORCE_TEXT"` on the command for each toolbar item.